# Scraping with requests and BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to get the content in the table to then put in a pandas dataframe in the following website: https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/soccer-predictions/premier-league/

I'm quite new to BS, but I believe that what I want would be something like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get(url = "https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/soccer-predictions/ligue-1/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
#print(soup.prettify())
print(soup.find("div", {"class":"forecast-table"}))
```

But of course, unfortunately this is returning "None". Any help and guidance would be amazing! 
I believe that the bit I need to get is somewhere in here (not really sure though):

```
<div id="forecast-table-wrapper">
      <table class="forecast-table" id="forecast-table">
       <thead>
        <tr class="desktop">
         <th class="top nosort">
         </th>
         <th class="top bordered-right rating nosort drop-6" colspan="3">
          Team rating
         </th>
         <th class="top nosort rating2" colspan="1">
         </th>
         <th class="top bordered-right nosort drop-1" colspan="5">
          avg. simulated season
         </th>
         <th class="top bordered-right nosort show-1 drop-3" colspan="2">
          avg. simulated season
         </th>
         <th class="top bordered nosort" colspan="4">
          end-of-season probabilities
         </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sep">
         <th colspan="11">
         </th>
        </tr>
```

Comment: So, is there a `div`, whose _class_ is `forecast-table`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `pandas` anyway, you can use the built-in table processing, like this:

```
pandas.read_html('https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/soccer-predictions/premier-league/',
  attrs = {
    'class': 'forecast-table'
  }, header = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are searching for a div, but it's a table, so it should be:

```
print(soup.find("table", {"class":"forecast-table"}))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/soccer-predictions/ligue-1/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class':'forecast-table'})
for i in table:
    tr = i.find_all('tr')
    for l in tr:
        print(l.text)
```

Output:

```
Team ratingavg. simulated seasonavg. simulated seasonend-of-season probabilities

teamspioff.def.WDLgoal diff.proj. pts.pts.relegatedrel.qualify for UCLmake UCLwin Ligue 1win league
PSG24 pts90.03.00.530.74.52.9+7897<1%>99%97%
Lyon14 pts76.32.10.719.69.19.3+2768<1%60%2%
Marseille13 pts71.12.00.918.38.311.4+1663<1%40%<1%
Lille19 pts63.71.70.916.78.612.6+9591%24%<1%
St Étienne15 pts62.71.60.914.710.912.4-1553%14%<1%
Montpellier16 pts64.01.50.713.912.411.7+2543%12%<1%
Nice11 pts62.01.60.913.510.014.5-7507%7%<1%
Monaco6 pts65.91.80.913.010.714.2+0508%7%<1%
Rennes8 pts63.41.60.813.010.514.5-3499%6%<1%
Bordeaux14 pts59.21.50.913.09.915.0-6498%5%<1%
Strasbourg12 pts59.21.51.012.610.814.6-2499%5%<1%
Angers11 pts60.41.50.912.610.215.2-54810%4%<1%
Toulouse13 pts58.21.50.911.912.014.1-104811%4%<1%
Dijon FCO10 pts57.71.61.112.28.517.3-124517%2%<1%
Caen10 pts55.61.41.010.812.414.8-104518%3%<1%
Nîmes10 pts54.91.51.110.711.615.6-134420%2%<1%
Reims10 pts55.31.30.910.312.315.4-144321%2%<1%
Nantes6 pts59.01.50.910.410.916.7-144225%1%<1%
Guingamp5 pts57.31.51.010.39.817.9-194130%<1%<1%
Amiens10 pts53.01.31.010.49.018.6-164031%<1%<1%
```

Comment: Any suggestion to get the team names separate from the points? This is how the code for teams looks like in the source: `<div class="name">Man. City<span class="record">19 pts</span></div>`